# Calculate time remaining Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, firebase, time

I am creating a social web app using Javascript and Firebase as my backend. The users of the app ask help for a problem they have and then the problem stays active for 24 hours and people can give solutions. I need to find a way to add to each post a timer that goes from 24 backwards with hours, minutes and seconds based on how long ago the post has been published, and when it gets to zero it gives that the problem has expired.

Comment: Use a count down timer starting with 24 hours when the problem is posted. and then trigger the expiry/deletion function when the count down timer hits zero. You could use jquery for timer.

Comment: @AnmolRastogi Thank you for your answer! How do I keep the timer on firebase for each post?

Comment: sorry man, actually i'm not sure how you could use it with firebase (never worked on it).

Comment: Store an expiry date/time. Then use local timer script based on that expire time. There are lots and lots of resources on web for countdown timers

Comment: @AnmolRastogi no worries and thank you for your help!

Comment: @charlietfl thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd typically put the timestamp of when the post was created into the database. E.g.

```
posts
  post1id
    question: "..."
    timestamp: 1525268563424
  post2id
    question: "..."
    timestamp: 1525268577811
```

Now you can check if the post has expired in your code with something list:

```
var millisecondsPerDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
if (Date.now() - post.timestamp > millisecondsPerDay) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I think I can now tweak this to suit my purpose!